# Archive page built from custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I have site with review posts.
There I can add custom field criteria.

How can I make tags from these custom field criterias?
I should get an archive page which displays all posts with selected criteria.

This is the code for the one custom field:

```
   <div class="mom_tiny_form_element">
   <?php $mb->the_field('custom_box_units_gametypes'); ?>
        <div class="mom_tiny_desc">
            <div class="mom_td_bubble">
                <label for="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>"><?php _e('Game Types', 'framework'); ?></label>
                <span><?php _e('Select one of the options', 'framework'); ?></span>
            </div> <!--bubble-->
        </div> <!--desc-->
        <div class="mom_tiny_input">
            <select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
                <option value="slot games" <?php $mb->the_select_state('slot games'); ?>><?php _e('Slot Games', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="table games" <?php $mb->the_select_state('table games'); ?>><?php _e('Table Games', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="instant win" <?php $mb->the_select_state('instant win'); ?>><?php _e('Instant Win', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="video poker" <?php $mb->the_select_state('video poker'); ?>><?php _e('Video Poker', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="arcade" <?php $mb->the_select_state('arcade'); ?>><?php _e('Arcade', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="virtual sports" <?php $mb->the_select_state('virtual sports'); ?>><?php _e('Virtual Sports', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="bingo/keno" <?php $mb->the_select_state('bingo/keno'); ?>><?php _e('Bingo/Keno', 'framework'); ?></option>
                <option value="pattern match" <?php $mb->the_select_state('pattern match'); ?>><?php _e('Pattern Match', 'framework'); ?></option>
            </select>
            </div> <!--input-->
            <?php $mb->the_field('custom_box_units_gametypes2'); ?>
        <div class="mom_tiny_input">
            <div class="mom_switch"><input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="on"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state('on'); ?>/><label><i></i></label></div>
        </div> <!--input-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

And this is for the frontend:

```
<?php if (isset($gametype) && $gametype == 'on') { ?>
<footer class="review-criteria-row">
    <div class="user-rate bars user-star-rate">
        <h3  class="review-criteria_title"><strong class="user_rate"><?php _e('Game Types:', 'framework'); ?></strong></h3>
        <div class="review-criteria_answer">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/tag/<?php echo do_shortcode($new_games_name); ?>"> <?php echo do_shortcode($games); ?></a>
        &nbsp
</footer> <!-- footer -->
<?php } ?>
```

So when visitor clicks on the slot games, an archive page will open with all reviews with this selected criteria